# How can I count and order in a custom way items of a list?

Tags: python, list, count

I have a list of keyboard keys which looks like this (but is much longer):

`pressed_keys = ['u', 'u', 't', 'q', 'q']`

I want to count them and order them in the way that appear on the keyboard. For example, for that list I would like to get [2,0,0,0,1,0,2,...etc] . I know collections.Counter, but It only gives the keys which were pressed.

Comment: `collections.Counter` is a dict: you can access the times pressed with the letter as key. Thus, you just need to iterate over the letters in the order of the relevant keyboard, and grab the amount from your counter using the individual letters from that iteration as key.

Comment: Use `counter.get(letter, 0)` for keys not present in the counter.

Comment: What keyboard are you using? They are not in that order on my qwerty keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this gives what you seek:

```
from collections import Counter
keyboard = 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm'
pressed_keys = ['u', 'u', 't', 'q', 'q', 's', 'p', 'a', 'm', 'h', 'a', 'm', 's', 't', 'e', 'r']
key_counts = Counter(pressed_keys)
[key_counts[k] for k in keyboard]

# [2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```py
In [37]: keyboard_order = list('qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm')

In [38]: pressed_keys = ['u', 'u', 't', 'q', 'q']

In [39]: from collections import defaultdict

In [40]: output = defaultdict(int)

In [41]: for key in pressed_keys:
    ...:     output[keyboard_order.index(key)] += 1
    ...:

In [42]: output
Out[42]: defaultdict(int, {6: 2, 4: 1, 0: 2})

In [43]: sorted(output)
Out[43]: [0, 4, 6]
```

What I'm doing is creating a list of the keyboard ordering. Then you just need to create a default dictionary with keys and values of 0 and count the frequency. Or use collections.Counter, whatever you want. You get the key index and the number of times it was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

With numpy it's easy:

```
import numpy as np

pressed_keys = ['u', 'u', 't', 'q', 'q','q']
pk = np.array(pressed_keys)                        # create a numpy array
chars, counts = np.unique(pk, return_counts=True)  # get the unique elements and count them

print(chars)
print(counts)
```

which gives

```
['q' 't' 'u']
[3 1 2]
```

**Now**, let's introduce a (arbitrary) keyboard and insert the counts at the right place:

```
keyboard = np.array(['a', 'b', 'u', 'f', 't', 'g', 'q', 'x', 'y', 'z'])  # an arbitrary keyboard
key_hits = np.zeros(len(keyboard),dtype=int)                             # initialize the key hits with zero
for ch, co in zip(chars, counts):                                        # insert the counts at the right place
    key_hits[np.isin(keyboard, ch)] = co

print(keyboard)
print(key_hits)
```

which gives:

```
['a' 'b' 'u' 'f' 't' 'g' 'q' 'x' 'y' 'z']
[0 0 2 0 1 0 3 0 0 0]
```